# PHP won't recognize quotation marks from html form

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I am using a very basic html form with submit button which calls my PHP which handles the input. The problem is my PHP will not recognize the " mark when I try to str_replace. Here is my PHP: (Note- the html text field input is pasted in from google docs)

```
<?php

    $article = $_POST['article'];
        //This contains: “This has quotes” from my html input field

    echo str_replace("”", "quote", $article);
        //Returns the input, without quote replacement
    echo addslashes($article);
        //Does not add slashes


    $quotes = "“This has quotes”";

    echo str_replace("“", "quote", $quotes);
        //Returns quoteThis has quotesquote as it should


?>
```

So, what about the HTML input is causing the input quote to not be recognized, and is there a way to fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see immediatley you have alot of varied quotes in play. To start with there are vertical single and double quotes " and ', and also left and right version of them also.

For this code your going to have to keep an eye on the encapsulating characters. So....

```
<?php

    $article = $_POST['article'];  //This contains: “This has quotes” from my html input field
    $article = str_replace('”', 'quote1', $article); // remove double left quote
    $article = str_replace('"', 'quote2', $article); // remove double vertical quote
    $article = str_replace("'", 'quote3', $article); // remove single vertical quote

    echo addslashes($article); //Does not add slashes

    $quotes = "“This has quotes”";

    echo str_replace("“", "quote", $quotes); //Returns quoteThis has quotesquote as it should

?>
```

You will notice in the above example, only 3 of the 6 basic quotes are managed, if you want to replace them all you will need to add a few new lines, shown below.

```
<?php

// REPLACE USING CHARACTER STRING
$article = str_replace('"',      'double vertical', $article); // replace double vertical
$article = str_replace("'",      'single vertical', $article); // replace single vertical
$article = str_replace('‘',      'single left',     $article); // replace single left
$article = str_replace('’',      'single right',    $article); // replace single right
$article = str_replace('“',      'double left',     $article); // replace double left
$article = str_replace('”',      'double right',    $article); // replace double right
// REPLACE USING CHARACTER STRING

// REPLACE USING CHATACTER CODE
$article = str_replace(chr(34),  'double vertical', $article); // replace double vertical
$article = str_replace(chr(39),  'single vertical', $article); // replace single vertical
$article = str_replace(chr(145), 'single left',     $article); // replace single left
$article = str_replace(chr(146), 'single right',    $article); // replace single right
$article = str_replace(chr(147), 'double left',     $article); // replace double left
$article = str_replace(chr(148), 'double right',    $article); // replace double right
// REPLACE USING CHATACTER CODE

?>
```

The above examples here show two such ways of performing these replacements, one using a character string and the other using the chatacters number. Either will do in this situation, but character code is often easier to look at.

Comment: ok- i implemented all three of those str_replace and the only one that was replaced correctly was the single quote, when I inputed all three. I also tried    $article = str_replace('\”', 'quote1', $article); but no luck.

Comment: Answer revised to show how to handle the additional quotes

Comment: Thank you so much! It turns out I needed to do it using the character code.

Comment: Please note: there are six replacements occuring, on six seperate characters. Please +1 the answer.

Comment: Yes I see, the chr(148) and chr(147) is what I needed.

Comment: Your very welcome, please +1 the answer if this solved your problem.